# php - WebSocket, pcntl_fork, close child process correctly

Tags: php, multithreading, websocket, fork

I install ratchet php websocket.
I do pcntl_fork in onMessage method to work with every client in new thread.

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {

    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid == -1) {
        $this->myPrint("cant create fork");
    } else if ($pid) {

    } else {
        // ..... $result
        $from->send($result);
        // $pid = getmypid();
        // exit($pid);

    }

}
```

if i try to close child process, client dont get any message. ($from->send($result) dont work).
if i comment exit($pid) .  Client get message.

How to close child process correctly ?

[image]

i tried to do exit with:

```
function _exit() {
    posix_kill(posix_getpid(), SIGTERM);
}
```

but, I still have a problem

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?