# Send message from forked onMessage Ratchet socket server

Tags: php, sockets, ratchet

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343348/php-websocket-pcntl-fork-close-child-process-correctly), since all action done by ratchet web sockets server take too long.

I used `pcntl_fork` in `onMessage` before doing the heavy logic and sending data to the connection to finally kill child process.

But the data never get sent, unless i omit the kill command.